# How to Scroll Down combo box (ActiveX Control) vba in excel 2013

Tags: excel, vba

I want to scroll down my combo box using my scroll button on my mouse.

[image]

Comment: what you tried so far ?

Comment: i tried to code it via vba but it doesn't work

Comment: Can you please post what you have tried till now? We cannot understand your question properly and you will not get an answer.  If you have tried to code it via vba, please post what you have tried.

Comment: You want to create a "combo-box" on the worksheet (not from userform)? If that's the case, you need to turn on the "developer" tab and add it through "insert". http://www.tracecode.com.au/blog/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/visual-basic-1.png

Comment: What i mean was, i want to scroll it down using "scroll button" on my mouse but whenever i scroll it down, the side scroll of the combo box not respond.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not clear, what you want? Do you want to drop down of your items by `vba`. If that you may use following sub.

```
    Public Sub Scroll_Down()
        Sheet1.ComboBox1.DropDown
    End Sub
```

When you click the button, it will expand combobox1 of your sheet.

[image]

Comment: Great! i also want to scroll down the list using my scroll button on my mouse. Thanks!

Comment: If it help you, you should accept (Green tick symbol) the answer.